# Picocli command hierarchy in JLine

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, interactive, picocli, jline3

I am using Pico CLI v4.0.0-alpha-3 & jline v3.  I have the following class (using annotations).  When I run the main class, I cannot seem to run the command and get the callable invoked.  I can invoke the callable if I simply pass in the parameters.

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "Test CLI",
        description = "CLI tool",
        header = "%n@|green test cli |@",
        footer = {"",
                "@|cyan Press Ctrl-D to exit the CLI.|@",
                        ""},
        version = "1.0.0",
        showDefaultValues = true,
        optionListHeading = "@|bold %nOptions|@:%n",
        subcommands = {
                Sync.class,
                Status.class
    })
public class Tester implements Callable<Integer> {

    private static final String PROMPT = "Test CLI> ";

    private LineReaderImpl lineReader;
    private PrintWriter out;


    @Option(names = {"-u", "--username"}, required = true, description = "user name")
    private String userName;

    @Option(names = {"-p", "--password"}, required = true, description = "password")
    private String password;



   final Tester tester = new Tester();
    final CommandLine cmd = prepareCommand(tester);
    final int exitCode = cmd.execute(args);
```

When I run the java application, and run the command with the parameters, the callable does not get invoked.  When I simply pass in the parameters, the callable gets invoked.  Any thoughts on how to fix this so that the CLI user has to pass in the command followed by the parameters.

Comment: Can you show examples of how exactly you are trying to invoke the command?

Comment: @RemkoPopma I added the call.  When i run the CLI application, the call only seems to be invoked when i pass in parameters (e.g. -u abc -p ab123) but not as Test CLI -u abc -p abc123

Comment: @RemkoPopma I have also tried using the jline v3 example referenced here: https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-shell-jline3

Comment: Understood now. I’ll post an answer a bit later.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I never realized but this can be quite confusing. I’ll update the documentation for the `picocli-shell-*` modules to explain this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Command Line Utilities**

I think that the way that java applications are packaged is what causes the confusion.
If your application was a single executable file, let's say `myapp.exe`, then you would invoke the app on the command line like this:

```
myapp -u xxx
```

If your application is a Java class, you need to invoke it like this:

```
java -cp mylib.jar com.myorg.MyApp -u xxx
```

So, the top-level command is the `com.myorg.MyApp` class itself, *there is no need to specify `myapp` as an argument to the `com.myorg.MyApp` class on the command line*.

Now imagine that your `myapp` application has a subcommand, called `sub`. Again, if your application was a single executable file, you would invoke the subcommand on the command line like this:

```
myapp sub --subcommand-options
```

As a Java class, you need to invoke it like below. Note that *here, you **do** need to specify the **subcommand name** as a command line argument* to the `com.myorg.MyApp` class:

```
java -cp mylib.jar com.myorg.MyApp sub --subcommand-options
```

> Side note: What people often do is create startup scripts for Windows and unix that allow you to execute your application as `myapp` instead of `java -cp mylib.jar com.myorg.MyApp`. One of the reasons that people are enthusiastic about GraalVM is that GraalVM native images solve this packaging problem and allow Java developers to distribute their applications as a single executable file.

Picocli's main use case is to facilitate creating command line utilities in Java. So it is very easy to do the above with code like this:

```java
package com.myorg;

@Command(name = "myapp")
public class MyApp implements Runnable {

    @Option(names = {"-u", "--username"}, description = "user name")
    private String userName;

    @Command // subcommand "sub"
    public void sub(@Option(names = "--subcommand-options") String option)  {
        System.out.printf("sub says hello %s!%n", userName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("myapp says hi %s!%n", userName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args);

    }
}
```

**Interactive Command Line Applications**

When you create an interactive CLI shell application with JLine, you need to keep in mind that the top-level command is *not specified on the command line*.

Therefore, all the commands that you want users to be able to type in the shell *should be subcommands*, like you describe in your answer.

The top-level command can still be useful to provide help to the users. One idea is to print a friendly help message followed by the usage help of the top-level command when the user enters an invalid command (or just hits enter without parameters).

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to use the command name once the CLI terminal was open.  I could just use the parameters without the command name.

I ended up moving the logic to a subcommand after which the subcommand can be invoked.  However, now the CLI displays the suggested command as "parent command + sub command" which I can see is quite confusing (and using that option does not produce the desired outcome).  I ended up removing the description from the parent command to take care of it.